# AWS invoke local Lambda Endpoint with Node.js SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-application-model

in the [SAM documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-start-lambda.html) there is the possibility shown to deploy your own lambda endpoint and call it with the Python SDK.

You just have to startup the local lambda endpoint with `sam local start-lambda` and then continue with

```py
# USING AWS SDK
 -------------
 #You can also use the AWS SDK in your automated tests to invoke your functions programatically.
 #Here is a Python example:

     self.lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda',
                                  endpoint_url="http://127.0.0.1:3001",
                                  use_ssl=False,
                                  verify=False,
                                 config=Config(signature_version=UNSIGNED,
                                               read_timeout=0,
                                                retries={'max_attempts': 0}))
    self.lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName="HelloWorldFunction")
```

My question is now, how can i do exactly the same with the Javascript SDK? I always get different errors about missing regions, not found hosts and unsupported parameters.
Do you have a solution for me?

Comment: Instead of saying "I get these errors when I try" show the actual code, and the actual error message, so we can help. We are here to help with issues, we are not here to provide a free code conversion service.

Comment: Yes i know, i was a bit in a hurry yesterday. Normally i provide enough code to understand my problems better. I vow improvement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AWS JavaScript SDK requires region and credentials to make requests. But for local endpoints you can use arbitrary values.

Following example works for me:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
  apiVersion: '2015-03-31',
  endpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:3001',
  sslEnabled: false,
  region: 'us-east-1',
  accessKeyId: 'any',
  secretAccessKey: 'any'
});

lambda.invoke({
  FunctionName: 'HelloWorldFunction'
}, (err, res) => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. My code looked almost the same, but something simply didn't work.